# How to convert a 4D numpy array of type int32 to tfrecords?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have hyperspectral dataset which is a numpy array with dimensions `(num_images, height=7, width=7, num_channels=144)` and datatype `int32`.

The label array is `(batch_size, num_classes=15)`. I want to convert it to `tf.records` and read it back correctly.

So far i have read many blogs and tried a lot of different ways all of which failed. Here is what i have tried?

The problem is the code does not throw an error when i train a model with it but it's accuracy results does not make any sense, when i compare it to the case when i train the model with numpy arrays.

The question is where in the code do i make a mistake?
Do I make any mistakes in my conversion to tfrecords and reading then back?

```
def wrap_int64(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def wrap_bytes(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def convert(images, labels, save_path, save_name):

"""

:param images: np.ndarray containing images with shape (num_images, 
 height, width, num_channels)
:param labels: np.ndarray containing labels with shape (num_labels,),
 i.e. one_hot=False
:param save_path: path in which we save the tfrecords
:return:
"""




out_path = os.path.join(save_path, save_name)
print("Converting: " + out_path)

assert images.dtype == np.int32

# Number of images
num_images = len(images)
print(num_images)
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(out_path) as writer:
    for i in range(num_images):

        # Load a single image
        img = images[i]
        label = labels[i]

        # Convert the image to raw bytes.
        img_bytes = img.tostring()

        image_shape = np.array(np.shape(image)).astype(np.int32)

        # Convert the image to raw bytes.
        #########################################################
        # There is no need to flatten each image!!!
        ###########################################################
        img_bytes = image.tostring()
        img_shape_bytes = image_shape.tostring()
        # Create a dict with the data we want to save in the
        # TFRecords file. You can add more relevant data here.
        data = \
            {
                'image': wrap_bytes(tf.compat.as_bytes(img_bytes)),
                'image_shape': wrap_bytes(tf.compat.as_bytes(img_shape_bytes)),

                'label': wrap_int64(label)

            }

        # Wrap the data as TensorFlow Features.
        feature = tf.train.Features(feature=data)


        # Wrap again as a TensorFlow Example.
        example = tf.train.Example(features=feature)

        # Serialize the data.
        serialized = example.SerializeToString()

        # Write the serialized data to the TFRecords file.
        writer.write(serialized)
```

#

```
def parse(serialized, num_classes, normalization_factor):
    features = \
    {
        'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'image_shape': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    }

    # Parse the serialized data so we get a dict with our data.
    parsed_example = \
    tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized=serialized,
        features=features)

    # Get the image, shape and label as raw bytes.
    image_raw = parsed_example['image']
    image_shape_raw = parsed_example['image_shape']
    label = parsed_example['label']

    # Decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type.

    # have to be converted to the exact same datatype as it was before 
      starting conversion to tfrecords

    image = tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.int32)
    image_shape = tf.decode_raw(image_shape_raw, tf.int32)

    # reshape the image back to its original shape
    image_reshaped = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)

    # let's cast the image to tf.float32 and normalize it. Let's 
    # change the label to one_hot as well.
    image_normed = normalization_factor * tf.cast(image_reshaped, tf.float32)
    label_one_hot = tf.one_hot(label, num_classes)

    # The image and label are now correct TensorFlow types.
    return image_normed, label_one_hot
```

#

```
def input_fn(filenames, num_classes, normalization_factor, train, batch_size=1024, prefetch_buffer_size=5):


    buffer_size = 10 * batch_size

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames)

    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: parse(x, num_classes, normalization_factor))
    if train:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size)

    # Allow infinite reading of the data.
        num_repeat = None
    else:
        num_repeat = 1

    # Repeat the dataset the given number of times.
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_repeat)

    # Get a batch of data with the given size.
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=prefetch_buffer_size)

    # Create an iterator for the dataset and the above modifications.
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    # Get the next batch of images and labels.
    batch_images_tf, batch_labels_tf = iterator.get_next()

    return batch_images_tf, batch_labels_tf
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use the `tf.train.Feature` for example
(assuming your labels are ints)

for the int values:

```
def _int64_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
```

and for the bytes:

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
```

them:

```
 data = {'label': _int64_feature(label),
         'image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(img_bytes))}
```

that should do the work

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry that I forgot to include them in the code earlier, but these are the exact same functions i used, and the code still gives error. I was wondering if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: I also asked this question as well which is perfectly reproducible and this time happens with random data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588177/tfrecord-coversion-is-not-being-done-correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
# load training set and test set
batch_images_tf, batch_labels_tf = \
    input_fn(
        filenames_train,
        FLAGS.num_classes,
        normalization_factor=FLAGS.normalization_factor,
        train=True,
        batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
        prefetch_buffer_size=5)
```

## Wrong way!!!!

```
batch_images, batch_labels = sess.run(batch_images_tf),sess.run(batch_labels_tf)
```

## Right way!!!!

```
batch_images, batch_labels = sess.run([batch_images_tf, batch_labels_tf])
```